# How to create a PHP if function to determine cut-off delivery time?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create a small if statement on a webpage to check if a parcel gets delivered today or tomorrow. However it is not working.

This is what I tried:

```
<?php if(date('G') < 11) : ?>
    <div class="single-product-delivery">   
        <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size: 20px; color: #0bbbef;"></i> 
        <span class="product-single-span">Order before 11:00, delivery tonight!</span>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="single-product-delivery">   
        <i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size: 20px; color: #0bbbef;"></i> 
        <span class="product-single-span">Order before 23:59, next day delivery!</span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This should work right? However I am seeing "Order before 23:59, next day delivery!" right now and the time is before 11.

Can someone help?

Comment: What's the timezone on your server? The same as where you are?

Comment: Timezone on my server is ```Tue 13 Aug 08:49:18 CEST 2019``` , but when I check it in PHP with ```<?php echo date_default_timezone_get(); ?>``` I get UTC

Comment: And the actual time here is 07:48, but still it should show then right? Because its all before 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working temporarily with your time zone. Using date_default_timezone_set is not a good idea. The effects are not manageable.

```
$localHour = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->format('G');
if($localHour < 11) ...
```